# How to embed whole angularjs app into existing app which is separately deployed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-component

I have application with logic similar to google's app switcher, let me call it `Wrapper`. This application take place across all google services and has consistent UI everywhere.

I am looking for solution to inject into my `Wrapper` application several finished different apps with their own styles, views and JS. They are written with different technologies like React and Angular.

How can I implement such architecture? Are Web-components a solution for this, if yes - please provide me some examples. (The aim is to deploy wrapper separately and all content applications too, so they will have consistent UI and logic from wrapper).

Please do not mention the `iframe`!

Comment: hello... have you find the example or solution?

Comment: I have tried many different approaches but eventually, I ended up with a custom micro-frontends framework. You can read more about it on Medium - https://medium.com/hackernoon/front-end-microservices-with-web-components-597759313393?source=search_post---------1

Answer (score 2):

We have done similar model called UI shell, where any developer can develop a microapp in any tech stack like angular, react, vue etc but the main app will consume them as part of its application and display them as part of the main app. Are you looking for similar approach.

Comment: I already implemented by myself - [Front-end Microservices](https://hackernoon.com/front-end-microservices-with-web-components-597759313393)